# Google column chart bug with the drawing in Web app

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-visualization

In my web app there is a google chart that uses dataTable(jsonObject) to draw the graphs and I have bugged data. Here is my code of calling the function :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() {

  function drawChart() {
             var myJson= $.ajax({
             url: "loadGraph.php",
             dataType:"json",
             async: false
            }).responseText;

  var visualization = new google.visualization.DataTable(myJson);

  var options = {
      title: "MyTitle",
      titleTextStyle: { fontSize: 16, bold: true },
      chartArea: { left: 32, right: 0,left: 52, width: 460, height: 180 },
      legend: { position: 'top' }
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
  chart.draw(visualization , options);
 }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>
```

My graph was correctly drawed, but recently a bugs occured. Please help

Comment: What is the anomaly in the drawing ? Is your bars not visualizing correctly, but the values from the code behind are okay ?

Comment: The graphs are filing all the chart space, but i just checked the json and the data shows that is okay

Comment: Post the JSON returned by your AJAX query.  Also, you have duplicate calls to `google.load` and `google.setOnLoadCallback`; the API only supports one of each, so remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my post on this matter : [Google column chart visualization from json object bug in MVC 4 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377467/google-column-chart-visualization-from-json-object-bug-in-mvc-4-c-sharp)

There is a bug on this type of displaying the charts. The good part is that the solution is pretty slick. Replace the values for the chart with this regex ->

```
myJson = myJson.replace(/"v":"(\d+)"/g, '"v":$1');
```

This will fix the visualization ;] Hope this helps

Comment: This help ,but is it more stable solution to the problem, because this looks like a way arround not a solution ?

Comment: You should think of a better solution from the code behind, but it is a workaround that can be used instead of changing the core. I use it at the moment and it seems to be working